# Filtrar varios parámetros en un input con vue js

Tags: javascript, html5, vue.js

estoy empezando con vue js, tengo un tabla que muestra los datos de un json, y un buscador que filtra los resultados. El problema es que solo consigo que filtre a partir de un valor (item.noticia_titulo_cas), alguien sabe como podría filtrar el resultado desde cualquier valor del objeto js? Muchas gracias.
Aquí el codigo js:

```
 <script>
                new Vue({
                    el: '#noticias',
                    created: function() {
                        this.getNoticias();
                    },
                    data: {
                        lists: [],
                        noticia_titulo_cas:''
                    },
                    methods: {
                        getNoticias: function() {
                            axios.get(urlNoticias).then(response => {
                                this.lists = response.data
                        });
                        }
                    },
                    computed:{
                        searchNoticia: function () {
                            return this.lists.filter((item) => item.noticia_titulo_cas.includes(this.noticia_titulo_cas));
                        }
                    }
                });

            </script>
```

Aquí el html:

```
<h3>Noticias</h3>
                <a href="noticia-nuevo-editar.php">[nuevo]</a>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar" class="form-control pull-right" style="width:300px;" v-model="noticia_titulo_cas"> <!-- Aquí querría abarcar todo el contenido del objeto js-->
                <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Fecha*</th>
                        <th>Título cas*</th>
                        <th>Trabajo*</th>
                        <th>Editar</th>

                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr style='width: 130px; overflow: auto;'  v-for="item in searchNoticia">
                            <td>{{ item.idNoticia }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.noticia_fecha }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.noticia_titulo_cas }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.lanak_titulo_cas }}</td>
                            <td><form action='noticia-nuevo-editar.php' method='POST'><input hidden name='idNoticia' v-bind:value="item.idNoticia"><input hidden name='idLanak'  v-bind:value="item.idLanak"><button type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-lg'><i class='fas fa-plus'></i></button></form></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Es mi primera pregunta, perdón si algo no está correcto. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, Existen dos posibilidades, la mas fácil tal vez sea buscar en cada uno de las propiedades del objeto así como ya lo estas haciendo con la propiedad filtrada, solamente agregándolo como opciones posibles, haciendo uso de OR lógico en javascript. A continuación muestro el ejemplo:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#noticias',
    data: {
        lists: [
        
            {
              idNoticia: 1,
              noticia_fecha: '2018-01-19',
              noticia_titulo_cas: 'Titulo CAS',
              lanak_titulo_cas: 'LANAK TITULO'
            },
            
            {
              idNoticia: 2,
              noticia_fecha: '2018-01-20',
              noticia_titulo_cas: 'Titulo DOS',
              lanak_titulo_cas: 'otro titulo'
            }
        ],
        noticia_titulo_cas:''
    },
    computed:{
        searchNoticia: function () {
            return this.lists.filter((item) => {
                return item.noticia_titulo_cas.toLowerCase().includes(this.noticia_titulo_cas.toLowerCase()) || 
                item.noticia_titulo_cas.toLowerCase().includes(this.noticia_titulo_cas.toLowerCase()) ||
                item.lanak_titulo_cas.toLowerCase().includes(this.noticia_titulo_cas.toLowerCase()) ||
                item.noticia_fecha.toLowerCase().includes(this.noticia_titulo_cas.toLowerCase());
            });
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="noticias"> 

<input type="text" placeholder="Buscar" class="form-control " style="width:300px;" v-model="noticia_titulo_cas">
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive mt-2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Fecha*</th>
        <th>Título cas*</th>
        <th>Trabajo*</th>
        <th>Editar</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style='width: 130px; overflow: auto;'  v-for="item in searchNoticia">
            <td>{{ item.idNoticia }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.noticia_fecha }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.noticia_titulo_cas }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.lanak_titulo_cas }}</td>
            <td><form action='noticia-nuevo-editar.php' method='POST'><input hidden name='idNoticia' v-bind:value="item.idNoticia"><input hidden name='idLanak'  v-bind:value="item.idLanak"><button type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-lg'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></button></form></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

> Si notas estoy convirtiendo a minúscula todas los strings antes de la comparación, para que el usuario no tenga que escribir exactamente el texto con mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Talvez otra solucion posible, un poco mas complicada, si quieres reutilizar el codigo, sea el de iterar por cada una de las propiedades del objecto con un for, de la siguiente manera:

```js
function buscarEnObjecto(objecto, palabra) {
  for (let key in objecto) {
    if (objecto.hasOwnProperty(key) && objecto[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(palabra) ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

new Vue({
    el: '#noticias',
    data: {
        lists: [
        
            {
              idNoticia: 1,
              noticia_fecha: '2018-01-19',
              noticia_titulo_cas: 'Titulo CAS',
              lanak_titulo_cas: 'LANAK TITULO'
            },
            
            {
              idNoticia: 2,
              noticia_fecha: '2018-01-20',
              noticia_titulo_cas: 'Titulo DOS',
              lanak_titulo_cas: 'otro titulo'
            }
        ],
        noticia_titulo_cas:''
    },
    computed:{
        searchNoticia: function () {
            return this.lists.filter((item) => {
                return buscarEnObjecto(item, this.noticia_titulo_cas.toLowerCase());
            });
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="noticias"> 

<input type="text" placeholder="Buscar" class="form-control " style="width:300px;" v-model="noticia_titulo_cas">
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive mt-2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Fecha*</th>
        <th>Título cas*</th>
        <th>Trabajo*</th>
        <th>Editar</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style='width: 130px; overflow: auto;'  v-for="item in searchNoticia">
            <td>{{ item.idNoticia }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.noticia_fecha }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.noticia_titulo_cas }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.lanak_titulo_cas }}</td>
            <td><form action='noticia-nuevo-editar.php' method='POST'><input hidden name='idNoticia' v-bind:value="item.idNoticia"><input hidden name='idLanak'  v-bind:value="item.idLanak"><button type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-lg'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></button></form></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

la función `buscarEnObjeto` se encargara de buscar en el cada propiedad del objecto y retornara true en el momento que encuentre alguna coincidencia en cualquiera de los valores.

Espero te ayude

Comment: Muchas gracias, ambas soluciones funcionan a la perfección. Finalmente opté por utilizar la función ya que me vale para otra tabla.

Comment: Que bueno que te funciono.

Comment: Y como seria de una tabla paginada ?

Comment: Dependeria de que es lo que estas usando. Si estas utilizando una libreria o lo estas haciendo desde cero. Lo mas recomendado si es una lista muy grande es utilizar el servidor para hacer la consulta y que el sea el encargado de hacer el filtro y retornar el resultado